# How would you cleanly follow the Stepdown rule in C/C++?

Tags: c++, abstraction

The Stepdown rule encourages to read the code like a top-down narrative. It suggests every class/function to be followed by those at the next level of abstraction so we can read the code descending in the level of abstraction.

In C/C++ you need to declare classes/functions before you use them. So how would cleanly apply the Stepdown rule here? What are some pros and cons of the following approach? Any better one?

```c++
void makeBreakfast();
void addEggs();
void cook();
void serve();

int main()
{
    makeBreakfast();
}

void makeBreakfast()
{
    addEggs();
    cook();
    serve();
}

void addEggs()
{
    // Add eggs.
}

void cook()
{
    // Cook.
}

void serve()
{
    // Serve.
}
```

Comment: It's only going to matter when you have a single source file. Definitions within `cook.cpp` are unordered with respect to definitions in `serve.cpp`

Answer (score 3):

My approach is like yours but with either making a class so the declaration can come after use, or put declarations in a header file.

Comment: Right, have the header as the table of contents, whereas the source file is the actual novel.

Comment: But the header should ideally only include declarations of functions that form the public interface of the module. If there are private functions that are only called from within the same file, the declarations of these functions should not go in the header.